# Java, try...catch in init or run

Tags: java, url

When I'm adding a throw Exception to run or init, i have an error which says:

```
ray.java:115: error run() in xray cannot implement run() in Runnable

public void run() throws Exception(

          ^ 

overriden method does not throw Exception 

1 error
```

i need try{..}catch for URL works. try{...}catch needs throw Exception for works.

Comment: Read concepts of overriding thoroughly.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`Runnable.run()` does not throw a checked exception. You cannot therefore implement `run() throws Exception` as it would *break the contract* of `Runnable` by throwing *unexpected exceptions*.

```
interface Runnable {
  // guarantees no checked exception is thrown
  public void run();
}

class Foo implements Runnable {
  @Override
  public void run() throws Exception {} // violates the guarantee
}
```

What you *can* do in general is the opposite (not applicable to `Runnable` though):

```
interface Foo {
  // Exception might be thrown, but does not have to
  public void bar() throws Exception;
}

class FooImpl implements Foo {
  // FooImpl does not throw exception, so you can omit
  // the throws; it does not hurt if consumer expect an
  // exception that is never thrown
  @Override
  public void bar();
}
```

To **solve your implementation issue** you either have to *catch and handle* the exception (nice solution) or *wrap it into a runtime exception* (less nice, but done from time to time). Runtime Exceptions do not need to be declared in a method signature:

```
class Foo implements Runnable {
  @Override
  public void run() {
    try {
    } catch (Exception e) {
      // either handle it properly if you can, or ...
      throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

The compilation error is correct. You cannot declare the method as throwing a checked exception. Catch the exception within the method instead.

```
@Override
public void run() {
    try {
       // invoke methods, etc
    } catch (SpecificException1 se1) {
      // error handling specific to SpecificException1  
    } catch (SpecificException2 se2) {
      // error handling specific to SpecificException2 
    }
    ...
}
```

Handle specific exceptions in order so that they can be handled accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Since the original signature of `run()` does not throw any exception, then you cannot throw a checked exception.

---

As a rule of thumb:

1. If a super method doesn't throw exception, then the overridden method can only:

   - not to throw any exception.
   - throw unchecked exception.
2. If a super method throws unchecked exception, then it is similar to case 1:

   - not to throw any exception.
   - throw unchecked exception.
3. If a super method throws checked exception, then the overridden method can only:

   - not to throw any exception.
   - throw unchecked exception.
   - throw checked exception, but it should be the same exception that the super method throws or a subclass.

Answer (score 0):

The overriding method must NOT throw checked exceptions that are new or broader than those declared by the overridden method. For example, a method that declares a FileNotFoundException cannot be overridden by a method that declares a SQLException, Exception, or any other non-runtime exception unless it's a subclass of FileNotFoundException.

Original method signature of `run()` doesn't throw any exception hence you cannot override that in your class and start throwing an exception.

Answer (score 0):

The interface Runnable contains void run(), because it is defined like that, you cannot alter it by adding a throws Exception to your overriding method.

Answer (score 0):

`void run()` from `Runnable` interface does not throw exception, that is the `contract`. In case your code within run is throwing an exception either handle it then and there or let the run-time pass it up the hierarchy.

Answer (score 0):

Try this..you cannot delegate errors from `run()`

```
public void run(){
    try{
          //something which CAN throw an exception
    }catch(Exception e){
          e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
```